# LEMP installation with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I tried many tutorials online, and need help to sort this out.

nginx is installed, but http://localhost/ returns a bin file to be saved

[image: 1]

Here is the site-available/default file.

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index info.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }



# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I used this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) to create a symbolic link of

```
usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

in the

```
usr/share/nginx/html
```

In the end I reinstalled everything. So, I'm again at the beginning.

Comment: What is the contents of that "bin" file? I guess there is some error message...

Comment: Anyway, `phpmyadmin` is written in PHP and you don't have PHP configured in nginx. Easiest is to use `php-fpm` and access it from nginx viac FastCGI.

Comment: It shows the contents of info.php... i have php-fpm installed.

Comment: I tried configuring php5-fpm in nginx. but failed.. used this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Then uncomment the configuration block starting with `location ~ \.php$` and enter there correct port / unix socket to your php-fpm.

Comment: Is there a way to revert back everything i did, and follow some simple steps to complete this configuration. stuck in this the whole day.

Comment: After uncomenting `location ~ \.php$` and restarting nginx, now localhost returns unable to connect

Comment: Do the configuration from the beginning your that guide and report back what exactly does not work, what error messages you get in nginx `error.log`. The guide is OK, so must be doing a mistake somewhere...

Comment: Did you uncomment the whole config block between `{ }` or only that single line? Unable to connect means there was syntax error and nginx did not start. Look at its `error.log` for the exact reason.

Comment: unable to find `error.log` file for nginx.

Comment: uncommented the whole config block between `{   }`

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` you should have line defining it, I have `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;`.

Comment: I guess you can have only one `fastcgi_pass` line. Uncomment only one of them - according on how you have configured `listen` in php-fpm.

Comment: Everything is solved i followed that guide. I did a simple mistake of not changing `location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }` to `location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is solved i followed that [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04). I did a simple mistake of not changing

```
location = /50x.html { root /usr/share/nginx/www; }
```

to

```
location = /50x.html { root /usr/share/nginx/html; }
```

As my system is 14.04.

I did changed that in the starting lines.